# replace values in a column into Data Frame with another value (same for all)

Tags: r, replace

My data frame consists of 21 columns, for this problem only one is relevant:
I want replace values 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 in a column **a** with the value 1 (in the same column).

beside of doing the code below for any value 2,3,4,5 i'm looking for something more elegant:

```
  df <- df %>% mutate (a = replace(a, a == 2,1))
  df <- df %>% mutate (a = replace(a, a == 3,1))
  df <- df %>% mutate (a = replace(a, a == 4,1))
  df <- df %>% mutate (a = replace(a, a == 5,1))
```

so i'm just stock with the condition "or" i need create inside the code...
any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace multiple columns using `across` and multiple values with `%in%`. For example, if you want to replace values from column `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(across(a:d, ~replace(., . %in% 2:5, 1)))
#For dplyr < 1.0.0 use `mutate_at`
#df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(a:d), ~replace(., . %in% 2:5, 1))
```

In base R, you can do this with `lapply` :

```
cols <- c('a','b','c','d')
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) replace(x, x %in% 2:5, 1))
```

Comment: but if i dont have chronological order in my values, how can i write it? such as 3,6,8,2

Comment: You can use `replace(., . %in% c(3,6,8,2), 1)`